# How to Import & export selected plugin data in worpdress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created one wordpress custom plugin in that plugin I have added 80 records on the test server database but I want to import this data on test database and export this chunk data in Live database.

Comment: How we can help you without checking your code. You have added 80 records. Does that custom post type? Does it your own custom table?

Comment: @Aki No It's not custom table. I am using wp_postmeta and wp_post table to save the data and add_post_meta method to save data